# Can someone help me unlock my MacBook?

Tags: mac, passwords, password-recovery, brute-force

can someone tell me how I brute force my MacBook air with mac os x snow leopard?
I have tried everything I can possibly think of!
I have an PC, can i use it?
Thanks!

Comment: Not much detail to go on here… What are you locked out of? Account, entire computer,  firmware lock, MDM lock? What have you tried so far? Snow Leo is actually pretty easy to bypass compared to a new Mac [which is *impossible*] but we need at least some effort from you. We can't see over your shoulder. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

NB: These instructions assume you do not have a firmware password or Full Disk Encryption (was that even a thing back in Snow Leopard?) set, and that the only problem is you don't remember the password to any user account.

1. Boot into *Single User Mode* by holding down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> at boot.

Note: If you are using a Bluetooth keyboard, hit the key combo as you hear the boot chime trailing off. Any earlier and the system will ignore the keys; any later is too late for the keys to have an effect.

2. Follow the on-screen instructions to check the root filesystem and then re-mount it read/write.
3. Remove the empty file that tells the system it's already run the first-run setup assistant, then flush those changes to disk and reboot:

```
     rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone  
     sync  
     sync  
     reboot
```

4. Go through the Setup Assistant that comes up, and create a new local admin account. Use that new account to reset the password on your old local admin account. Then you can log out of the new account and log into the old account and delete the new account if you want.